# Creating a JSON file to use the RPushbullet package

Tags: json, r, package

I recently discovered the `RPushbullet` package and have been unsuccessfully trying to set it up for use. [The author's blog](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rpushbullet.html) provides a step by step guide to the installation of the package; however, I encounter a few issues. Here are the first two steps:

1. Get the app (Google Chrome or mobile device)
2. [Create a Pushbullet account](https://www.pushbullet.com/)

The next step consists of inserting some information in a JSON file `.rpushbullet.json` in the home directory. I had never used a JSON file before that so I read a few articles on that format. Anyway, the information to put in the JSON file is:

- The API key in the account settings page
- The ID of the device(s)

The reason for the third step is that when the `RPushbullet` package is loaded, it attempts to read the JSON file in order to obtain the information in it.

I created a file with the help of [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and named it .rpushbullet.json (which is the name required by the package) for it to become a JSON file (and Windows identified it as one). However (and this is the first problem), when I load the package, the file is not found for some reason. Here is the error message:

```
> library(RPushbullet)
Attaching RPushbullet version 0.1.1.
No file ~/.rpushbullet.json found.
Consider placing the Pushbullet API key and your device id(s) there.
```

The library does not "see" the JSON file I created. The error message suggests that I add the API key and the device ID to the file. The author actually provides a code which generates the json code to copy and paste in the file:

```
> library(RJSONIO)
> cat(toJSON(list(key="..your key here..", devices=c("..device a..", "..device b.."))))
{
 "key": "..your key here..",
"devices": [ "..device a..", "..device b.." ] 
}
```

As mentioned above, the API key is easy to obtain because it is in the account settings page. The device ID, on the other hand, I could not obtain from the Pushbullet website. After some research, I learnt that it was possible to obtain the device ID from within `R` with the `jsonlite` package. Here is the code and the ensuing error message:

```
> fromJSON(pbGetDevices())$devices[,c("iden", "nickname")]
Error in fromJSON(pbGetDevices()) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'content' in selecting a method for function 'fromJSON': Error: Neither option 'rpushbullet.key' nor entry in package environment found. Aborting
```

Apparently, the JSON file I created in the home directory is not "seen" by any package.

I need your help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if it says that it cannot find a `.rpushbullet.json` file, where are you saving it? It should be within whichever directory is returned by `Sys.getenv("HOME")` (e.g., `/home/username`, `/Users/username`, ...)

As I'm playing with it, it appears that what the API is returning has changed ever-so-slightly, because `RJSONIO::fromJSON()` is no longer interpreting it the same. (This might be a bug?) There are several ways I've found to reduce the return properly. I'll mimic `pbGetDevices()` and mention where I diverge:

```
apikey <- "a1...98"                ## replace with the string of your API key
txt <- sprintf("%s -s %s -u %s:", RPushbullet:::.getCurl(),
               "https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/devices", apikey)
jsonres <- system(txt, intern = TRUE)
## res <- fromJSON(jsonres)        ## this doesn't work anymore
res <- Reduce(rbind, RJSONIO::fromJSON(jsonres)$devices)[,c('iden','nickname')]
```

The variable `res` now has a data.frame with two columns, the device ids you need, and the nicknames show you (as you save them to your `.rpushbullet.json` file) which is which.

(Oh, ensure that notepad++ is not secretly appending a `.txt` to the filename. This is a common windows thing, helping to "protect" you from the debilitating inconvenience of being exposed to file extensions.)

Comment: When I tried `Reduce` I got a dimension problem but `fromJSON` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to quote the documentation of the package (and echoing what @r2evans wrote):

> One possibility is to use a file \code{.rpushbullet.json} in the
>   \code{$HOME} directory. (Note that on Windows you may have to set the 
>   \code{$HOME} environment variable.)

If you want the convenience of a file, put it into `$HOME`. Create `$HOME` on an OS that does not have it.

You are not forced to use that file. You can equally well use any R startup file to populate `options()`.

Comment: on a Mac I can't put a . in front of the file name, as that is "reserved for the system". I try to set options via `options(key = "key", devices = "Chrome")` but I am clearly failing to set the options correctly. Any advice?

Comment: Dunno. Mock/double up the code into a local function which gets the required information via means blessed by Cupertino?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this too. For me, it was the result of installing and loading `RPushbullet`, *followed* by adding the `.rpushbullet.json` file to my HOME directory. At that point, the package did not yet recognize the new `.rpushbullet.json` file.

Yet simply detaching and then reloading the package made it recognize it:

```
install.packages("RPushbullet")
library(RPushbullet)
pbSetup()
detach("package:RPushbullet", unload=TRUE)
library(RPushbullet)
pbPost("note", title="Works perfectly now!")
```